# MySQL : Understanding performance difference between hardcoded fk_id and join queries

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to understand why among the two MySQL queries I've mentioned below, the first one is slower. All I'm doing is replacing a join on the foreign key with a hardcoded value which should (intuitively) be as fast or even faster than the second query.

First query :

```
SELECT date_column, currency, SUM(IF(key = 1,amount *-1, amount * 1)) AS amt
FROM main_table 
WHERE ((x = "123" and y in ("a","b))
     OR (x = "234" and y in("a")))

AND amount is NOT NULL 
AND fk_id = 13
AND code IN ("xyz","xy")
GROUP BY date_column, currency
```

Explain Output:

```
id select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        filtered    Extra           
1   SIMPLE      table1  NULL        ref     fk_id           fk_id       5       const   29234242        0.54    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Second Query :

```
SELECT main_table.date_column, main_table.currency, SUM(IF(main_table.key = 1,main_table.amount *-1, main_table.amount * 1)) AS amt
FROM main_table 
INNER JOIN lookup  
ON main_table.fk_id = lookup.pk_id
WHERE ((main_table.x = "123" and main_table.y in ("a","b))
     OR (main_table.x = "234" and main_table.y in("a")))

AND main_table.amount is NOT NULL 
AND lookup.name LIKE "%test%"
AND main_table.code IN ("xyz","xy")
GROUP BY main_table.date_column, main_table.currency
```

Explain Output:

```
id select_type  table       partitions  type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref             rows        filtered    Extra           
1   SIMPLE      lookup          NULL    index   PRIMARY         unique_key  416         NULL            13          11.11       Using where;Using index;Using temporary;Using filesort 
1   SIMPLE      main_table      NULL    ref     fk_id           fk_id       5           lookup.pk_id    7308560     0.54        Using where;
```

The second query is consistently faster by ~30-40 seconds.

Details about the tables(haven't added the create table as its a huge table with almost 100s of columns and lots of indexes) :

```
1. main_table has ~61 million rows. lookup_table has 13 rows.
2. main_table.fk_id = lookup.pk_id has ~61 million rows(entire table). 
3. Lookup.name like "%test%" filters 1 row from lookup and 16.88 million rows from the result of main join lookup.
4. Number of rows which satisfy fk_id = 13 is 16.88 million rows (same as the join).
5. main_table.fk_id is a non unique index. lookup.pk_id is a unique (primary) index.
6. lookup.name is part of a unique composite index, with sequence 1. 
7. main_table.currency is part of a composite non unique index  with sequence 2.
8. All other columns have no index.
```

Also, despite the EXPLAIN estimating different number of rows for both queries, when I checked the Handler_read_% counts (flushed to 0  before running the queries) for both queries, its almost the same ~16.88million, the second one reads 13 extra rows. I'm using MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: the first check 29 million rows but the joined  only checks 7,3 Million which would male the second much faster

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't make any sense and why the joined query would check only 7.3 million rows since the index being used on main_table is same for both queries . And the Handler_read counts also confirms this, it shows both of them read around 16 mil rows.

Comment: the first query filters all 29 Million with the where clause. the second makes first th join and then filters the rest out, that is why only 7,3 million

Comment: It's not an answer to "why", but perhaps by adding a subquery to the FROM from the first query where you apply only your big fk_id = 13 filter, you might coax the optimizer to mimic the behavior of the second query.

Comment: The `a` and `b` in the second Explain do not match the table names in the query.  Please fix.